# Duvida com string, extrair dados

Tags: c#, json, string

Tenho a seguinte `string`

```
[{"tipo":"simnao","pergunta":"rwerwerwerewr ?","tag":"#acimadopeso","resposta":"","$$hashkey":"object:410"},{"pergunta":"werwerwerwer ?","tag":"#diabetes","resposta":"","$$hashkey":"object:412"},{"pergunta":"werwerwer ?","tag":"#idoso","resposta":"","$$hashkey":"object:414"}]
```

Preciso extrair para uma lista somente as palavras que contem o "#", ou seja preciso jogar num `List` as palavras #acimadopeso e #diabetes. como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Busca as palavras que contenha `#`

Você pode fazer desta forma, a explicação esta nos comentários do código

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string stringJson = "[{\"tipo\":\"simnao\",\"pergunta\":\"rwerw#erwerewr ?\",\"tag\":\"#acimadopeso\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:410\"},{\"pergunta\":\"werwerwerwer ?\",\"tag\":\"#diabetes\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:412\"},{\"pergunta\":\"werwerwer ?\",\"tag\":\"#idoso\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:414\"}]";
        
        //Separa a string por aspas 
        string[] arrayString = stringJson.Split('\"');
        
        //Procura as strings que contenha "#"
        var listString = arrayString.Where(x => x.Contains("#")).ToList();
        
        //Mostra o resultado
        listString.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\n", i));
    }
}
```

[Executar](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YRXIy8)

## Busca as palavras que começam com `#`

Na pergunta você falou que queria as palavras que contenham `#`, porem acredito que você queira as palavras que começam com `#`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string stringJson = "[{\"tipo\":\"simnao\",\"pergunta\":\"rwerw#erwerewr ?\",\"tag\":\"#acimadopeso\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:410\"},{\"pergunta\":\"werwerwerwer ?\",\"tag\":\"#diabetes\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:412\"},{\"pergunta\":\"werwerwer ?\",\"tag\":\"#idoso\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:414\"}]";
        
        //Separa a string por aspas 
        string[] arrayString = stringJson.Split('\"');
        
        //Procura pelas strings que começam com "#"
        var listString = arrayString.Where(x => x.FirstOrDefault() == '#').ToList();
        
        //Mostra o resultado
        listString.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\n", i));
    }
}
```

[Executar](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gSEcYJ)

Answer (score 5):

Como se trata de um JSON recomendo usar a biblioteca [Json.NET Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para obter o dado que você deseja.

Basta fazer um parsing usando a classe `JArray` e num `foreach` obter os valores da chave `tag` para que você possa preencher sua lista de strings, exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "[{\"tipo\":\"simnao\",\"pergunta\":\"rwerw#erwerewr ?\",\"tag\":\"#acimadopeso\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:410\"},{\"pergunta\":\"werwerwerwer ?\",\"tag\":\"#diabetes\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:412\"},{\"pergunta\":\"werwerwer ?\",\"tag\":\"#idoso\",\"resposta\":\"\",\"$$hashkey\":\"object:414\"}]";     
        JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);      
        var tags = new List<string>();      
        foreach (var a in array)
            tags.Add(a["tag"].ToString());      
    }
}
```

Saída `tags.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));`

> `#acimadopeso`
>   `#diabetes`
>   `#idoso`

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LzsHMg).